# Protect class instances of multithreading access

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, concurrency

I have a C++ class with many instances, and I want to make my application thread safe.
This class has a member and a function that handles it, for example:

```
class MyCls {
  int x;
  void f() { x++; }
};
```

I need to protect this member, so as far as I see it I have 2 options:

1. Add a global Critical Section and
   enter it before touching this member.
2. Add a Critical Section to the class
   so each instance will protect its own member.

Both solutions are a huge overkills:

1. Two different instances should not be sync at all.
2. The OS should handle millions of Critical Sections, where there are actually very few collisions.

Is there another solution or multithreading design patters I can use?

Comment: There are locks which do not require any special initialization at all, and only consume resources while threads are blocking. For example, here's Microsoft's one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904937.aspx

Comment: Please, use 4 indents for code formatting.

Comment: why the C tag on this question ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but I think the problem might be solved by using [Software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) mechanism. There's a bunch of [implementations for C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#C.2FC.2B.2B).

Comment: STM is composable in contrast to other mechanisms (locks, mutexes, semaphores etc.) See [Papers on transactional memory](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm) by [Simon Peyton Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Peyton_Jones), a major contributor to the design of the Haskell programming language.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first concern, each instance should have a member mutex to provide a separate critical section for each.

As for the second, I'm sure that most pthread implementations use a [futex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex) implementation for their mutexes. This means that they're pretty fast when there is no contention and only require OS intervention when there is a contention.

Comment: The core idea should be the same. Any decent OS should provide system calls for synchronization mechanisms that have very little overhead. And any library providing synchronization abstractions (like mutexes) should make proper use of it. I was only speaking to my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use locks or critical sections, then the simplest solution is not to keep the state in the object itself. If you change your class like the following, it will be thread-safe:

```
// Class has no state, only operations on data. So it
// is thread-safe by nature.
class MyCls 
{
    int foo(int x = 0)
    {
        return ++x;
    }
};

// Usage
MyCls obj;
int x = obj.foo(); // x = 1
x = obj.foo(x); // x = 2
```

Comment: This might do the trick in certain cases (that's why I didn't downvote it), but I think mostly we (at least I) want is our objects to encapsulate their data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need to increment that member (or similar simple arithmetic), you just need atomic operations.

- Most (all?) modern CPU support them
  with native instructions.
- I don't know about other compilers,
  but those from the gcc family have
  them as builtins.

Unfortunately there seems not to be a standardized interface to these, but the upcoming C standard (C1x) will have them.